# Importing equations generated in subpackage to be solved in another subpackage

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, packages, contexts

I have a package which contains two subpackages: one ("`MOTSimulator`MOTGenerator") which generates a systems of differential equations of the form

```
x1'[t] == f[x1[t],x2[t],...]
x2'[t] == g[x1[t],x2[t],...]
...
```

and to be saved to a file and another ("`MOTSimulator`MOTSolver) that solves such a system.

My problem is how to export the equations generated with MOTGenerator to a file which can later be solved with the MOTSolver.

I have seen an answer saying I should pass the symbols for the equation as arguments but it is not obvious when generating the equations what the xi variables are or how many of them there are.

When I define the t and xi symbols in the MOTGenerator package's private context and then export them to a file I get "MOTSimulator`MOTGenerator`Private`t" and "MOTSimulator`MOTGenerator`Private`xi" in the file, which makes it hard to pass to MOTSolver.

Comment: an alternative to passing the variables is to return them: I guess the code knows which variables it generated, so it could return them along with the equations... Another possibility which would get rid of the context problems is to use formal symbols which were introduced for such purposes...

Comment: The formal symbols route is interesting. Do you know how that could be achieved with indexed variables such as the xi above?

Comment: It is not well known and probably poorly documented, but you can not only use symbols but also expressions like x[1] in most mathematica functions which need variables, e.g. Solve and NDSolve. I think that this most probably would be possible in your case, too. It would most probably also solve issues with generating symbols for these indexed variables...